# Реализуются ли поля в неявном виде в случае с автоматически реализуемыми свойствами в C#?

Tags: c#

> С помощью автоматически реализуемых свойств можно упростить код, в то
> время как компилятор C# будет прозрачно предоставлять вам резервное
> поле.
>
> [Официальное руководство](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Что значит "прозрачно предоставлять"?

```cs
public class Person
{

  public uint ID { get; init; }
  public required string Name { get; init; }  
  public required string Email;
  
}
```

Насколько я экспериментировал, в случае со свойством `Name` не было автомтически сгенерировано поля `_name` или `name`. Или оно сгенерировано так, что я не могу получить к нему доступ?

Comment: у генерированного поля специальное имя, которое нельзя создать в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поля генерируются, но доступа у вас в коде к ним нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]